# Ruby not giving me an output?

Tags: ruby

I am using replit because I don't have ruby legitimately set up yet. I'm very new to coding and have minimal knowledge (everything my friend taught me in about 3 hours) and am quite confused. I was typing a code to test something, but when I ran it, it gave me no output.

```
class Hands 
  attr_reader :name, :element, :skill, :mana, :attack, :fire, :water, :lyfe

  def initialize(name, element, skill)
    @mana = 100
    @name = name
    @element = element
    @skill = skill
  end

  def attack
    if @element = fire
      puts "25"
    elsif @element = water
      puts "15"
    elsif @element = lyfe
      puts "10"
    end
  end
end

player1 = Hands.new('Boyd', 'Fire', 'Craft')

player1.attack
```

This is my code so far, and from what I know it should work. However when it runs it gives me nothing despite the puts command being in place.

Answer (score 1):

You've made three common mistakes.

First, using `=` (assignment) rather than `==` (test for equality). This works because assigning a value to a variable (in this case an instance variable) returns that value, which is then tested for whether it is true or not, *but* it does not test if the two things are equal.

```
if @element = fire
  puts "25"
```

Is basically the same as writing:

```
@element = fire
if @element 
  puts "25"
```

Secondly, you have used `attr_reader` to create a `fire` method to read the value in the `@fire` instaance method, but you have not initialized that `@fire` variable, so it is `nil`.

Consequently, all of your `if` and `elsif` branches are only triggered is `nil` is true, but since `nil` is *never* true, none of these branches are executed. This is why you see nothing printed.

Thirdly, your conditional expression is not exhaustive. There's no `else` triggered if none of the other conditions are true. In the event none of the branches of a conditional expression are executed, the conditional expression returns `nil`, which you can see happen in your case if you run the code in `irb`.

As a design note, it seems you intend to compare `@element` to a constant. You more likely want something like the following:

```
  def attack
    if @element == "fire"
      puts "25"
    elsif @element == "water"
      puts "15"
    elsif @element == "lyfe"
      puts "10"
    end
  end
```

Or using symbols:

```
  def attack
    if @element == :fire
      puts "25"
    elsif @element == :water
      puts "15"
    elsif @element == :lyfe
      puts "10"
    end
  end
```

You could streamline these a bit by using `case`.

```
  def attack
    case @element
      when :fire
        puts "25"
      when :water
        puts "15"
      when :lyfe
        puts "10"
    end
  end
```

But to ensure we can compare `@element` properly, we should first downcase it and convert to a symbol. This way we don't have to compare to all possible spellings or worry that we're doing a string to symbol comparison that will turn false.

```
  def attack
    case @element.downcase.to_sym
      when :fire
        puts "25"
      when :water
        puts "15"
      when :lyfe
        puts "10"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This should make the rest of the code easier now that I know how to avoid the problem.

Comment: If you feel this has answered your question, feel free to accept and/or upvote.

Comment: _"you have not initialized that @fire variable"_ – since `@element` is set to `'Fire'` in the example code, it has to be initialized to `@fire = "Fire"` to get it working which seems quite redundant (having a variable with a static string value that matches its name). Chances are the OP simply wants `@element == "Fire"` or maybe `@element == :fire` along with some `@element = element.downcase.to_sym` conversion. It would be nice if you could provide a working code snippet.