# Not displaying certain parts of the initialize - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am making a class, and when I try to run a command, some of the numbers will not show up.

```
class Summons
  attr_reader :name, :strength, :health
  attr_writer :name, :strength, :health
  
  def initialize(name, strength)
    @name = name
      if @strength == "1"
        @health = 25
        @mana = 25
      elsif @strength == "2"
        @health = 50
        @mana = 50
      elsif @strength == "3"
        @health = 100
        @mana = 75
      end
  end

  def health
    puts "#{@name} has #{@health} health"
  end
end
  
summon1 = Summons.new('Test',  '1')
summon2 = Summons.new('Test2',  '1')
summon3 = Summons.new('Test3',  '1')
summon4 = Summons.new('Test4',  '2')
summon5 = Summons.new('Test5',  '2')
summon6 = Summons.new('Test6',  '3')
```

This works fine, but when I run the health command, it would say "Test6 has   health" and not give me the actual number.

```
 def initialize(name, strength)
    @name = name
    @health = health <---------------
      if @strength == "1"
        @health = 25
        @mana = 25
      elsif @strength == "2"
        @health = 50
        @mana = 50
      elsif @strength == "3"
        @health = 100
        @mana = 75
      end
  end
```

Adding the `@health = health` where the arrow is did not help, as it made it display everything under the class, but still no integer. Maybe it's the strength system I have set up, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it. Any help and explanation would be lovely.

Comment: How could I fix it? Sorry, I'm still fairly new to ruby.

Comment: I think you might also be clobbering your `attr_reader` for :health by defining a method called `health`.    That may not be the problem but it is something that looks a little funny.

Comment: `@strength` is never assigned, so it will always be `nil` and never be equal to either `'1'` or `'2'` or `'3'`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I completely overlooked that.

Comment: This looks like pretty much the same issue in the question you asked yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71663849/ruby-not-giving-me-an-output

Answer (score 1):

[Instance variables](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Instance+Variables) like `@strength` have a default value of `nil`.

So without setting a value, your

```
if @strength == "1"
```

is equivalent to:

```
if nil == "1"
```

which will obviously never be true. (same for the other comparisons)

To fix this, you could either use the passed argument which is hold by the local variable `strength` (without `@`):

```
def initialize(name, strength)
  @name = name

  if strength == "1"
    # ...
  end
end
```

Or you could assign the argument to `@strength`: (which you might want to do either way)

```
def initialize(name, strength)
  @name = name
  @strength = strength

  if @strength == "1"
    # ...
  end
end
```

Note that in the latter example, you can use either `strength` or `@strength` in your `if` after the assignment because they are the same at that point.

Comment: Stefan is right. Just on a stylistic note, if you have a getter method for an instance variable, it’s best practice to always use that, rather than referring to the instance variable itself. So, I would use `if strength == “1”` in the next line

Comment: @bodacious `strength` would refer to the local variable. In order to call the getter method (with the same name), you'd have to use `self.strength == "1"` or `strength() == "1"`. (or eliminate the ambiguity by renaming the argument)

Comment: Oh crap you're right! Thanks for the correction